# Sorting multidimensional array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let say I have an array of

```
x = [[5, 9, 7, 17, 13, 0], [8, 10, 16, 35, 7, 5], [10, 17, 5]]
```

I want to sort the value so that it will look like this:

```
x = [[0, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 10, 13, 16], [17, 17, 35]]
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
x = [[5, 9, 7, 17, 13, 0], [8, 10, 16, 35, 7, 5], [10, 17, 5]]
y = sorted(sum([i for i in x],[]))
result = []
for i in x:
    temp = []
    for j in range(len(i)):
        temp.append(y.pop(0))
    result.append(temp)
print(result)
```

result:

```
[[0, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 10, 13, 16], [17, 17, 35]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is given by [@leaf_yakitori](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67787220/14867730) please look at it. Now I just added this code to reduce time `complexity from O(n^2) to O(n)`

```
x = [[5, 9, 7, 17, 13, 0], [8, 10, 16, 35, 7, 5], [10, 17, 5]]
y = sorted(sum([i for i in x],[]))
result = []
ind = 0
for i in x:
    result.append(y[ind:ind + len(i)])
    ind += len(i)

print(result)
```